# What is the closest latency efficient AWS region for GCP us-central1 region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, hybrid-cloud

I am evaluating a multi-cloud setup and would like to find the closest latency efficient AWS region for GCP's `us-central1` region, my options in AWS are `US East (2)` and `US West (2)`. I was unable to find any service/guide that would give me this mapping.

A couple of Stack Overflow answers used manual scripts to find this mapping. Is there any resource or better way to find AWS region for a GCP region?

Comment: Start instances in each and see what the response times between them are.

Comment: Latency and bandwidth are very easy to measure at a single instance in time but very hard to predict. There are so many factors outside your control that will make most measurements useless tomorrow. Unless you know the actual routes the traffic will take now and in the future, and the details of capacity, bandwidth, and utilization, you can only generalize.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think the choice between US East & US West in AWS for US Central in GCP will still make a difference by 10s of ms in latency and the decision would matter. I am surprised there are no continuously monitored benchmarks for multi-cloud latency.

Comment: Latency rarely makes a difference in real-world cloud services when you factor client -> service -> resources. There are special cases where latency is very important. However, you have not provided details whereby advice can be offered that is fact-based. At this point, I can only offer generalizations and recommendations. In other words, based upon the details in your question, either region is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not aware if there are some tool to measure multi-cloud latency, in GCP there is a tool called [Performance Dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/performance-dashboard/how-to/using-performance-dashboard#global-latency) in the Network Intelligence menu, where you can choose up to 5 GCP regions to measure the latency among Google’s Network this could be from 1 hour to 6 weeks, the latency graph shows the median latency across all VMs deployed on Google Cloud. The vertical axis shows the median latency in milliseconds (ms), and the horizontal axis shows the change over time, I hope this information gives you a overview to make your decision and compare with AWS

Answer (score 0):

You could use the results in the aforementioned Performance Dashboard, and make a simplifying assumption that one of Google's "east" regions is close to AWS'east and similarly for "west."  Additionally, if you don't have an account yet, there is a public dashboard which shows [inter-region latency and throughput](https://datastudio.google.com/c/u/0/reporting/fc733b10-9744-4a72-a502-92290f608571/page/70YCB) in Google Cloud, and you could use the same sort of assumption.

But ultimately, unless/until there is a public inter-cloud latency tool available your best bet is probably to fire-up some VMs and take some measurements. John Hanley's caveats about what you see "today" may not be what you see "tomorrow" are definitely worth keeping in mind.